# ROS 2 (Foxy Fitzroy) Compatibility with Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: ros2, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Will ros2 (Foxy Fitzroy) work on the latest version of Ubuntu (currently 21.10)? If not, will it be supported in the future? Should I install Ubuntu Focal Fossa (20.04) instead?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/388956/will-ros2-(foxy-fitzroy)-work-on-the-latest-version-of-ubuntu-(currently-21.10)?-if-not,-will-it-be-supported-in-the-future?-should-i-install-ubuntu-focal-fossa-(20.04)-instead?/) by [DMT](https://answers.ros.org/users/87561/dmt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-10-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It will not be "made available" in any other distributions than those it was released under, but you may always build it manually, but you won't have access to binaries to install / support. I would recommend 20.04. 21.10 is not an LTS Ubuntu distro, unless there's something very particular that requires it.

But you can always use Docker to install and work with ROS 2 Foxy on 21.10.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2021-10-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-10-19**:
And by:

> It will not be "made available" in any other distributions than those it was released [for]

@stevemacenski means the ones listed here: [REP 2000: ROS 2 Releases and Target Platforms](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-2000.html#foxy-fitzroy-may-2020-may-2023).

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2021-10-20**:
Ah yes, good point to mention that, thanks.